# Pycharm can't find the Interpreter(2)

Tags: python, pycharm, conda, interpreter

my first queation was here
[Pycharm can't find the Interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64522786/pycharm-cant-find-the-interpreter/64652346#64652346)
but now i have a additional Question.

Thank you so much for your answers. I heard it one last time to work with the Python interpreter. I found soemthing in Interent https://superuser.com/questions/1437590/typing-python-on-windows-10-version-1903-command-prompt-opens-microsoft-stor Under Apps and Features, there are an application execution aliases. I turned that off.

[image]

Then I restarted Pycharm and wanted to create a new project. Suddenly he couldn't find an interpreter on my PC and suggested that I download the PYthon interpreter 3.8 or 3.7 from the Internet. Normally the Python interpreter should be located in this directory C: \ Users \ Username \ AppData \ Local \ Programs \ Python \ PythonXX That was the case with my colleagues. But why not with me?

[image: ![enter image description here]

In the end I gave up and just wanted to work with the Conda, but I got a similar message here too

[image]

[image]

Do these two problems coincide? The problem must be with my laptop because everything worked out for my friends. Please help me if u have any Ideas. So far I haven't been able to work with Pycharm at all.

Thank you

Comment: Before you went the Conda route. Why did you give up? What was the error?

Comment: I gave up because Pycharm couldn't find the Python interpreter on its own. It worked for everyone else in the group and they didn't have to install the interpreter themselves. Before I wanted to start working with Conda, I wanted the Python interpreter to work independently. We usually work with Conda. This doesn't work either. Are these two problems related?